# Error in Zend_Config_Ini

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework, any idea how I solved this :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' 
    with message 'parse_ini_file(\\CONFIG\APP.INI) [<a href='function.parse-ini-file'>function.parse-ini-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Config\Ini.php:184  
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Config\Ini.php(125): Zend_Config_Ini->_loadIniFile('/config/app.ini') 
#1 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application.php(375): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('/config/app.ini', 'development') 
#2 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application.php(85): Zend_Application->_loadConfig('/config/app.ini') 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\tesis\index.php(23): Zend_Application->__construct('development', '/config/app.ini') 
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Config\Ini.php on line 184
```

Comment: Read the error -- follow the information within the error. Find the ini file. Find out why it can't be found/read/opened.

Comment: Please search before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840860/fatal-exception-in-loading-ini-file or http://serverfault.com/questions/306300/php-fatal-error-zend-uncaught-exception

Comment: There should be a `.ini` file in config directory in which you can write configuration settings of your application. ini parser couldnt parse a `.php` file.